# PopUpWindow dismiss issue

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I have to show a popupwindow. If i show it in click event of the ImageView, Then i call dismiss it hides. But when i show it in Touch event of ImageView, then dismiss event calls, but the popup not hides. What are the reasons for this error?. How can i solve it?

The code i used to show popup window is

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels; //320       
    CabotMessageHandler.printConsole("width of screen"+width);

    //show Popup
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
       this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallerytoppopup, null, false);
    pw = new PopupWindow(
       popupView, 
       width, 
       30, 
       true);
    // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
    pw.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.popupanimation);
    pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.webview), Gravity.TOP, 0, 30);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find out the problem. The touch event calls twice, and two popups created. That was the reason to not hide the Popup when dismiss called.(One popup hides and other remains there).